# Why my user agent is MSIE 7.0?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-11

The login page has both `header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge");` header and `<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` header tag. But when I log in my user string I don't get IE11, I get `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)` which is IE7. Also in F12 I can see that my Internet Explorer is at Edge mode.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. See under 'IE11 for the desktop on 64-bit Windows 8.1 Update with compatibility view enabled'.

Answer (score 4):

as per this [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx)

> **Compatibility View**
>
> If the user chooses to render a site in
> Compatibility View (click Tools > Compatibility View Settings) then IE
> will send a User-Agent string that mimics Internet Explorer 7’s UA
> string:
>
> ```
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C)
> ```

Most probably it would be in developer mode,
check if disabling Developer mode helps.